# year should be 4 digits only , only then script should paas

Tags: shell, scripting, date

I mean `$yy` should be `2019`, `2020`, `2021`, etc.

**`$yy` should fail if it is `20199` `201987`**

It should be 4 digits only.

How to check this condition..

```
yy =$1
if [ $yy > 4 ] ----- something like this
then
echo "Year should be 4 digits only"
fi
```

Comment: add more context

Answer (score 7):

In a POSIX shell:

```
case $yy in
  ([[:digit:]][[:digit:]][[:digit:]][[:digit:]])
    echo OK;;
  (*)
    echo >&2 not OK;;
esac
```

Which you could also put in a function like:

```
valid_year() case $1 in
  ([[:digit:]][[:digit:]][[:digit:]][[:digit:]])
    true;;
  (*)
    false;;
esac
```

And then use in an `if` construct like:

```
if valid_year "$yy"; then
  echo OK
else
  echo >&2 not OK
fi
```

With ksh93 you can shorten to:

```
case $yy in
  ({4}(\d)) echo OK;;
  (*) echo >&2 not OK;;
esac
```

And in `zsh -o extendedglob`:

```
case $yy in
  ([0-9](#c4)) echo OK;;
  (*) echo >&2 not OK;;
esac
```

With bash/zsh/ksh93/yash, you can also use:

```
if [[ $yy =~ [[:digit:]]{4} ]]; then
  echo OK
else
  echo >&2 not OK
fi
```

To only check the length (in number of characters) of a variable, in addition to `case $yy in (????)`, you can do:

```
if [ "${#yy}" -eq 4 ]; then
  echo OK
else
  echo >&2 not OK
fi
```

Other more convoluted POSIX approaches using the `[` utility to check that a variable is 4 character  long and contains no character other than digits would be with:

```
if [ "${#yy}" -eq  4 ] && [ -n "${yy##*[![:digit:]]*}" ]; then
  echo OK
else
  echo >&2 not OK
fi
```